# Missing Decimal value in Datagridview

Tags: datagridview, decimal

I have used the below answer to show decimal values in my Visual Basic 2010 DGV.

***Using code you can set the DataGridView.DefaultCellStyle property.***

You can also do this in the designer by:

```
1.Right clicking your DGV and select Edit Columns. The Edit Columns dialog appears.
2.Select your column on the left side of the dialog and click the DefaultCellStyle property field to bring up the CellStyle Builder.
3.In the Builder dialog click Format which brings up the Format String Dialog.
4.Make your selections in this dialog (select Numeric type, which allows specifying number of decimals to display) and save your changes.
```

My problem is that when I enter new values via a textbox, binded to the DGV, the DGV show the decimal places but not the actual value that I have entered.  Ex : I enter 20.25, click the save button.  In the DGV the value of 20.25 show.  As soon as I close the program and open it again the value in the DGV show 20.00 and not 20.25 as entered.

How can I fix this problem ?

Comment: how do you persist the values that users enter in the cells ?

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution simply.i have searched along two days,found it finally. -your db column type must be Money or number,double,single. -Update datagridview event "CellFormatting" as below code.

```
private void dataGridView2_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
   {
       if (this.dataGridView2.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Aidat")
       {
          string deger=(string)e.Value;
          deger = String.Format("{0:0.00}", deger);
       }
   }
```